# Using BeautifulSoup on Twitter to get retweet count

Tags: python, twitter, beautifulsoup

I'm aware I can use the Twitter API for this, but I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to extract the retweet count for the following example tweet:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = 
BeautifulSoup('https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/758828659922702336', 
'lxml')

retweet_count = soup.find('div', {'class': 'js-tweet-stats-container tweet-
stats-container'}).find('ul', {'class': 'stats'}).find('li', {'class': 'js-
stat-count js-stat-retweets stat-count'}).contents

print(retweet_count)
```

I'm trying to print out the 'contents' so I can see where to go next to extract the retweet count (currently at 4,288 for this example).

However, even at this stage, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I would be very grateful if someone can tell me where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to get an API key and ask the API these things. https://github.com/bear/python-twitter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `BeautifulSoup` object takes a string representing markup as a parameter (see [Making the soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup)). You'll need to get the contents of the page first. For example, using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library:

```
import requests

html = requests.get('https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/758828659922702336').text
```

The other issue was that you weren't accessing the element that contains the retweet count. The result was instead several markup elements:

```
<li aria-hidden="true" class="js-stat-count js-stat-retweets stat-count">
<a class="request-retweeted-popup" data-activity-popup-title="4,288 retweets" data-compact-localized-count="4.3K" data-tweet-stat-count="4288" role="button" tabindex="0">
<strong>4,288</strong> Retweets
      </a>
</li>
```

To fix this, you'll need an call to `find` to get the anchor tag, and use of the `attrs` dictionary to get the `data-tweet-stat-count` attribute: `.attrs["data-tweet-stat-count"]`

The final product to get the retweet count is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/758828659922702336').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

retweet_count = soup.find(
    'div', {'class': 'js-tweet-stats-container tweet-stats-container'}
).find(
    'ul', {'class': 'stats'}
).find(
    'li', {'class': 'js-stat-count js-stat-retweets stat-count'}
).find(
    'a', {'class': 'request-retweeted-popup'}
).attrs["data-tweet-stat-count"]

print(retweet_count)
```

This prints out `4288`.